# Jhipster access control policy not working

Tags: java, jhipster, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to disable access to all microservice API in one of my gateways. This is because in this gateway I only want to publish the angular app.

I'm trying this, but it don't seems to work:

> https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#acl

Debugging the gateway, I see that de `AccessControlFilter.java` is working and trying to return a FORBIDDEN HttpStatus in the `run()` method, but I get access to the api, and a 200 code response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, rather than disabling the zuul proxy entirely, I would change the zuul properties to setup routes manually :

```
zuul:    
  ignoredServices: '*'   
  routes:
    app1: 
      path: /app1/** 
      serviceId: app1
```

Add only the routes that you need.

Comment: Twanks! Works perfectly. This is the solution I was looking for... I don't undestand why they didn't put this on the documentation.

Comment: They documented it: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compeltely disable API proxying for all services, the easiest and safest way is to disable Zuul completely and very likely Eureka too by removing `@EnableZuulProxy` and `@EnableDiscoveryClient` from your application.

This way your gateway is no longer a gateway, but it would be easier to just serve your angular app from a plain spring boot app or even from nginx.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just remark that I have also to disable all @Inject annotations of 'RouteLocator' beans in the code.